# How to check if all input values are empty in jquery each?

Tags: jquery, each, is-empty

I have an each and need to check if all input fields are empty and do some action. SO i did the following

```
jQuery(".page-template-sitecheckout .mainwrapper .shipping_addresses_checkout_view.checkout_shipping_column_withoutmargin .form-row.validate-required input").each(function () {
        var checkoutfieldsvalue = jQuery(this).val();
        if(checkoutfieldsvalue === ''){
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('checkout_invalid_fields_parent');
            jQuery(this).addClass('checkout_invalid_fields');
        }else{
          jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('checkout_invalid_fields_parent');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('checkout_invalid_fields');
            jQuery('.checkout_btn_prev_to_shipping').fadeIn().show();
            jQuery('.page-template-sitecheckout .mainwrapper .shipping_addresses_checkout_view').fadeOut().hide();
            jQuery('.page-template-sitecheckout .mainwrapper .billing_info_checkout_view').fadeIn().show();
            jQuery('.checkout_btn_prev_to_cart, .checkout_btn_next_to_billing').fadeOut().hide();
        }
    });
```

With this code when even one input has a value it passes to **else** statement. So how i can check for every single input field value emptiness and do some action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are expecting.

```
var count=0;
$('.page-template-sitecheckout .mainwrapper .shipping_addresses_checkout_view.checkout_shipping_column_withoutmargin .form-row.validate-required input').each(function(){
if($(this).val == ""){
count++;
}
});
if(count == 0)
{
//do something here
}
```